# MySQL - Selecting single entry per category

Tags: mysql, sql

My apologies. I have edited the below into 2 table, Im just having a bit of confusion.

---

I have a tables very similar as the ones below and I wanted to show all the table2-class 1 but only 1 random item per each table1-category

Sample Item Table1

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+
|   ID    |   Item Name   |    Category   |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
|   01    |    Item A     |     Cat 1     |
|   02    |    Item B     |     Cat 1     |
|   03    |    Item C     |     Cat 2     |
|   04    |    Item D     |     Cat 2     |
|   05    |    Item E     |     Cat 3     |
|   06    |    Item F     |     Cat 3     |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

Sample Item Table2

```
+---------------+---------------+
|    Category   |     Class     |
+---------------+---------------+
|     Cat 1     |       1       |
|     Cat 2     |       1       |
|     Cat 3     |       2       |
+---------------+---------------+
```

I wanted to show all the table2-class 1 but only 1 random item per each table1-category

Desired Result

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+
|   02    |    Item B     |     Cat 1     |
|   03    |    Item C     |     Cat 2     |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

*(This is within my PHP script)*

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: Look at function `RAND` use `GROUP BY` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: Thanks Marc B. Actually mine is kind of different, my whole scenario is: I have an Inventory (SQL); I used 2 serial numbers, item number and category number. I have around 1000 items and around 750 categories. I need to do a loop in PHP to display all the category and I only need to display a random Item per category. I don't think I can use "UNION ALL".. and yeah, changing the inventory format is not an option

Comment: It's a good design to create a separate table called Categories

Comment: yes I agree Kazi Tanvir Ahsan.. but Im having a bit of confusion on how to apply Peterm solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT t.id, itemname, category
  FROM
(
  SELECT 
  (
    SELECT id
      FROM table1
     WHERE category = t.category
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 1
  ) id
    FROM table1 t
   GROUP BY category
) q JOIN table1 t
    ON q.id = t.id
```

Note: *using `RAND()` is very costly*

Output:

```
| ID | ITEMNAME | CATEGORY |
|----|----------|----------|
|  1 |   Item A |    Cat 1 |
|  3 |   Item C |    Cat 2 |
|  6 |   Item F |    Cat 3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f69a23/2)** demo

Comment: Hi Peterm, this looks great! I will try this and post an update later. Thanks very much!

Comment: Awesome! that works like charm,even with out joining second table.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT id, itemname, category FROM (
  SELECT id, itemname, category FROM sample_table 
  ORDER BY RAND()
) AS tmp
GROUP BY category
```

Note that this query is totally valid in MySQL
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: This relies on MySQL group by extensions that are explicitly documented as unsafe:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Comment: It looks a bit similar to Peterm.. I want to stick with Peterm solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to do this is with a correlated subquery.  To get the `item_id`:

```
select category,
       (select item_id from sample s where s2.category = s.category order by rand() limit 1) as item_id
from sample s
group by category;
```

To get the rest of the item information, join that back in:

```
select s.*
from (select category,
             (select item_id from sample s where s2.category = s.category order by rand() limit 1) as item_id
      from sample s
      group by category
     ) c join
     sample s
     on s.item_id = c.item_id;
```

Comment: Hi, I think this will work too however I want to stick with Peterm solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the above edited scenario, I used the below query and it works fine except that it doesn't randomize the entry of each category:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1,Table2
WHERE Table2.Class = '1'
 AND Table1.Category = Table2.Category
GROUP BY Table1.Category ORDER BY RAND()
```